# Why is my Downloadmanager not showing notifications?

Tags: android

Why is my download manager not showing any notifications despite of having the

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />` permission in the manifest?

```
   request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
```

it works when I do this but it only shows notification upon completion

```
  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
```